# Euler's function and cyclicity

Tags: number-theory

What is the remainder when $17^{100000000\ldots}$, with $n$ zeroes is divided by $20$? I.e.:

$$
17^{10^n} \mod 20 = \ ?
$$

My approach: I can solve it by Euler's totient function ; $17^8=1 \mod 20$, so remainder is $1$.

But I want to know if the following method will fetch the result: $17$ divided by $20$ gives $-3$ as remainder and $-3$ raised to any multiple of $10 \mod 20$ gives $1$?

Is this logic correct? 
I think it works only for positive remainder.

Comment: What do you mean with a "multiple of $10$ mod $20$" ?

Comment: @Peter "(-3 raised to any multiple of $10$) modulo 20"

Comment: @Peter 3^10x mod 20

Comment: @GeorgeCarlin Of course you can use negative bases (which often simplifies things)

Answer (score 3):

Modular arithmetic doesn't care about positive or negative. $17$ and $-3$ behave in exactly the same way modulo $20$. They are both representatives of the modulo 20 conjugacy class
$$
\{\ldots, -23, -3, 17, 37, \ldots\}
$$
and thus one might even say they are *equal*, under some interpretations of modular arithmetic (they are equal "in $\Bbb Z_{20}$", for those who know what that means). So yes, that would work.

Note that $(-3)^2 = 9 = 10-1$, so 
$$(-3)^4 = (10-1)^2 = 100-20+1\equiv 1\pmod{20}$$
is probably the fastest way to get to your answer.

Comment: I was about to post an answer using FLT and CRT, but I think given OP's level of background, this is the superior answer. +1

Comment: @DonThousand Seing as they mention Euler's totient function, one might imagine that the OP already knows Euler's theorem. Which is basically what FLT and CRT gives you when you combine them. So I wouldn't say it would be unreasonable.

Comment: say they are equal

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee Thanks. Although if you had explicitly said it was a typo, I would've understood what you meant a few seconds faster.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $\ \gcd(a,20)=1\,\Rightarrow\, \color{#c00}{x^{\large 4}\equiv 1}\pmod{20},\,$ being true mod $4$ and $5$.

Thus if $\,f_n = a^{\large 10^{\Large n}}$ then $\bmod 20\!:\ \bbox[7px,border:1px solid #c00]{f_{n+1} \equiv {f_n}^{\large 2}}\ $ by $\, f_{n+1} = {f_n}^{10}\equiv \color{#c00}{({f_n}^{\large 2})^{\large 4}} {f_n}^{\large 2}\equiv {f_n}^{\large 2}$

So $\,\smash{\begin{array}{c | c } n & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & \cdots  \\ \hline f_n & a & a^2 & \color{#c00}1 & 1 &\cdots  \end{array}}\,$ by  $\, \bbox[3px,border:1px solid #c00]{\rm squaring}\,$ repeatedly.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $10^n = 0$ mod $8$ for $n \geq 3$, so $10^n = 8m$ for some $m$. So $17^{10^n} = 17^{8m} = (17^8)^m$ which gives $1$ mod $20$.